# Laravel 5.5 - How to query notifications for follower with created_at timestamp?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5, eager-loading

A user can be a follower and/or a leader. Here userA and userB (both leaders) were followed by userC (follower) at different times (see `followers` table below for `created_at` timestamp).

To illustrate the issue, I will first layout the template:

```
userX action (year) // template to understand issue below

userC followed userA (2016)
userA added postA/notification (2017)
userC should get notification in feed, since they followed userA a year BEFORE their post

userB added postB/notification (2018)
userC followed userB (2019)
userC should NOT get notification in feed, since they followed userB a year AFTER their post
```

To accomplish this, I tried this query but it does not work correctly:

```
$user = App\User::find(3); // follower
$leaders = $user->leaders()
                ->with(['leaderNotifications'=>function($query){
              $query->where('notifications.created_at','>','followers.created_at');
                }])
                ->get();
```

I think the issue is related to the `created_at` not being queried correctly. Here is the exact setup to see it locally:

**1) DB table name/data**

`users`

[image]

`followers`

[image]

`notifications`

[image]

**2) Models**

```
// User
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;

    // Pivot Table
    public function leaders() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', ‘followers’, 'follower_id', 'leader_id')
                  ->withPivot('created_at'); // need timestamp to compare against notification timestamp
    }

    public function leaderNotifications() {
        return $this->hasMany(DatabaseNotification::class, 'leader_id')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the correct notifications for the current follower `userC`, meaning only the new notifications **after** they followed a leader, not the leader's old notifications **before** they were followed by the current user.
It’s also worth noting that the final query should be able to `paginate->(20)` of these notifications at a time, since it will be tested with a million rows, so we need to ensure it's **efficient/scalable** and can be paginated.
What would an efficient/scalable query be for this issue?

Comment: try using `DB::raw('followers.created_at')`

Comment: @Ben Do you know how to get the query to scale? When I have 10k - 1m rows for the follower, I can't seem to be able to get Mehran Prs query below to work and php runs out of memory, so it is not efficient/scalable. I don't really need the leaders() info (since I have it in the notification's data), maybe don't even need eloquent, but not sure how to do it with `DB::raw` where a follower has 10k - 1m leaders, and 1 leader has 10k - 1m posts (trying to paginate by 20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved it in case it helps others:

```
$user = App\User::find(3); // follower
$leaders = DB::table('notifications')
             ->join('followers','followers.leader_id','=','notifications.leader_id')
             ->where('followers.follower_id', $user->id)
             ->whereRaw('notifications.created_at > followers.created_at')
             ->paginate(20);
```

No need for eager loading or complicating it even more. Just a simple `DB` query handles it!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) For raw query in Laravel you should using `whereRaw`.
>
> 2) When using `with()`, Laravel get data in two query , first 
>   get result of parent query and then using result for getting `with()` ,
>   If you want to use pivot columns of first query in `with` closure,you can
>   join.

Try this :

```
$user = App\User::find(3); // follower
$leaders = $user
          ->leaders()
          ->with(['leaderNotifications'=>function($query) use ($user){
              $query->whereRaw('notifications.created_at > followers.created_at')
                    ->join('followers','followers.leader_id','=','notifications.leader_id')
                    ->where('followers.follower_id',$user['id']);
                 }])
            ->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work/scale on 10,000 to a million rows. Only on a small number of rows. Trying to have this query work efficiently and not run out of memory when fetching the follower's leader notifications limited to 20 per page.

Comment: Yeah,but I'm tried to don't change your query template !!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think my approach was not correct, it was just my attempt to get it to work, which seems like it wouldn't scale too well. I upvoted your answer because you helped me with the `whereRaw` :)